# Redirect magento site

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, .htaccess

I need to redirect the whole website to a specific url 
i.e to

```
 domain.com/customer/account/create.
```

using htaccess?
How I can do that. I tried the following stuff it it show redirection loop

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule !^/?(customer/account/create|.*\.css|.*\.js)$   http://local.com/customer/account/create [R=302,L]

    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ $1.php
    RewriteRule ^home\.php$ index.php 
    RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
```

Comment: Maybe you should skip this specific rewrite rule in the destination site's htaccess.

Comment: I didn't get you want you are saying

Comment: You are redirecting with a rule like: redirect FROM X to http://anotherdomain/X, but if the same rule is applied also in the "anotherdomain", then it will redirect in an infinite loop. So what I am suggesting is to remove that rewrite rule only on "anotherdomain".

Comment: can u suggest me some rules for that..
and one more thing I want to redirect to a url in same domain

Comment: I tried your example and it worked. Maybe you are editing a .htaccess file which is not in the root of your Magento? That would answer the problem.